# B-tree: delete a non-leaf node?

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

Im studying B tree and in the book they said that:

1. If the key k is in node x and x is a leaf, delete the key k from x.
2. If the key k is in node x and x is an internal node, do the following.

a. If the child y that precedes k in node x has at least t keys, then find the predecessor k' of k in the subtree rooted at y. Recursively delete k', and replace k by k' in x. (Finding k' and deleting it can be performed in a single downward pass.)

b. Symmetrically, if the child z that follows k in node x has at least t keys, then find the successor k' of k in the subtree rooted at z. Recursively delete k', and replace k by k' in x. (Finding k' and deleting it can be performed in a single downward pass.)

c. Otherwise, if both y and z have only t- 1 keys, merge k and all of z into y, so that x loses both k and the pointer to z, and y now contains 2t - 1 keys. Then, free z and recursively delete k from y.

My question is this: In case 2.a.
Can someone explain me with example: Recursively delete k', and replace k by k' in x.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have b tree with the degree t = 4:

```
   26,      49,      60
27,31,34,36     51,55,56,58
```

Suppose `y = [27,31,34,36]`, `x = [51,55,56,58]` are not leaf nodes and you want to delete key `k = 51`. Let `K = 49` be the key in the parent node which splits `x`  and `y`.

Find the predecessor of `k` which is the rightmost key `k'` in the subtree `y` (which could contain integers between 37 and 48 in this example, say `k' = 40`). Set `k = K = 49` and `K = k' = 40` and delete `k'` recursively (which is actually the first case of the deletion procedure when the node is leaf). The resulting b tree looks like

```
   26,      40,      60
27,31,34,36     49,55,56,58
```

Comment: An excellent description.  Insertion and especially deletion in B-trees can be a very complex procedure involving the "rolling" of many nodes up and down the tree. The algorithms are made much more complicated by the desire to *keep* the tree more-or-less "in balance" all the time. Insertion and deletion are therefore potentially very-expensive operations, so that lookups remain consistently fast.

Comment: Where did you get the 40 from? It wasn't in there when you started out to delete 49...

Comment: 40 is `k'`, predecessor of `k`, not shown on the diagram, but it's the rightmost key of `y`, supposedly in some of `y`'s children (the comment in parenthesis in the answer).